# Initialize google firebase connection in app engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to initialize a firebase database connection in a cron job. However I only found the old document which is not updated after the new firebase release in May. Can anyone please let me know how I can establish google firebase connection in app engine? (Should we use the firebase server SDK?)

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#objectives